# Problem adding firebase firestore to a react.js project using webpack

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add firebase firestore to my project in which I'm using webpack and I'mg getting this error when tryin to add data to the firestore:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/firestore'

My code looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from "../firebase/firebase";
import 'firebase/firestore';

class User extends React.Component {

     constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
               email: " ",
               fullname: " "
          }
     }

     updateInput = (e) => {
          this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
          });
     }

     addUser = (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const db = firebase.firestore();
          db.settings({
               timestampsInSnapshots: true
          });
          const userRef = db.collection("users").add({
               fullname: this.state.fullname,
               email: this.state.email
          });  
          this.setState({
               fullname: " ",
               email: " "
          });
     };

  render() {
    return (
         <form onSubmit={this.addUser}>
               <input
                    type="text"
                    name="fullname"
                   placeholder="Full name"
                   onChange={this.updateInput}
                   value={this.state.fullname}
               />
               <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                   placeholder="Full name"
                   onChange={this.updateInput}
                   value={this.state.email}
               />
               <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          );
     }
}
     
export default User;
```

and the firebase file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
   ...
};
  
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

I could really use some help with this because it's the first time I'm working with react and webpack and it's all very confusing. :D Thank you!

Comment: did you `npm install firebase`?

Comment: I installed it using yarn add

Comment: could you also do it with npm and see if there is any change?

Comment: I tried, but I got the same error in the terminal and a bunch others in the firebase folder in node modules. :D

Comment: respectively this error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'promise-polyfill' in ./node_modules/firebase/utils/promise.js

Comment: That looks like more like a webpack/babel issue. Have you considered using Create React App?

Comment: Yes, I've done that and it works now. Thanks a lot! :)